# Add an annotate object as virtual field to get serialize

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

**Models**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Element(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

**Annonate code**

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> q = Category.objects.all().annotate(element_count = Count('element'))

>>> print q[0].element_count
223
```

And I want to serialize it with the django default json serializer but it takes only fields

How I can add an annotate result as a virtual field to my field list in a queryset.
That it looks like a field and that I can work with as a field
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean on `Category` - like `Category.objects.filter(element_count=223)`?

Comment: Can you show us a "pseudo-code" of what you want to do?

Comment: I added some more things